# importing the Lucene library into NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, lucene

I am using NetBeans to develop a desktop application 
I want to integrate the Lucene search engine from Apache. I have downloaded the Lucene-4.1.0

I would like to know what is the best way to import the Lucene library into the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: It is not different than adding any other jar to your library folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools / Libraries from the main menu. Click "New Library..." (I suggest 
naming it "Lucene-" plus the version you are using).

On the Classpath tab, click "Add JAR/Folder..." and select the jar files 
you need from where you downloaded Lucene. For Javadoc, select the 
docs/api directory from your download (at least, that's where it was for 
the version we use). NetBeans will tell you if he can't find Javadoc at 
the location you select.

Now you can just add your new library to your project. The process is 
similar for any external libraries you want to use.

**EDIT**
(right click you project)Project -> properties ->Libraries -> Add Library

Comment: I am using NetBeans 7.2.1 but don't seem to find the "New Library" button from the Tools menu list, any suggestions